# Output part of two-way binding doesn't work for custom directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to implement a directive with a property that would support a two-way binding like this: `[(appfocused)]="isFocused"`. A component could set its `isFocused` property to true to focus on an element but the variable would get reverted to false once the element loses focus.

I've read ([here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) and [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html)) that the key to implementing this kind of binding is having two properties for `@Input` and `@Output` named the same but with the output one suffixed with `Change`. So this is my implementation so far (in TypeScript):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appfocused]'
})
export class FocusedDirective implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
    @Input('appfocused')
    focused: boolean;

    @Output('appfocused')
    focusedChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'blur', () => {
            this.setFocused(false);
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.focused) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    private setFocused(value: boolean) {
        this.focused = value;
        this.focusedChange.emit(this.focused);
        console.log('focused set to ' + value);
    }
}
```

The input property works fine but I can't get the output property to work. Thanks to the `console.log` call, I know the `focusedChange.emit()` line is being hit but it has no effect on the value the property is bound to.

[Here is a working example (plunker).](https://plnkr.co/edit/gVht017KaDeyjTeTlgtf?p=preview) It includes a dummy component which displays and sets the value of the `isFocused` property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <textarea [(appfocused)]="isFocused"></textarea>
    </div>
    <a (click)="focus()" href="#">Focus</a>
    {{isFocused}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  isFocused = false;

  focus() {
    this.isFocused = true;
  }
}
```

Pressing the Focus link focuses on the `textarea` as expected. However, clicking out of it does not reset the `isFocused` variable. Pressing the link again has no effect - the value of `isFocused` was already true so Angular doesn't detect any changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the article you've mentioned stated, for the two-way binding shorthand syntax to work the output's name has to be the same as the input **plus the "*Change*" suffix**.

So you're almost there - you just have to name the `@Output()` properly: not "*appfocused*", but "*appfocused**Change***" instead:

```
@Output('appfocusedChange')
focusedChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I was thinking this rule only applied to the name of the variable...

Comment: Yeah, that can sometimes be confusing - I usually just keep the attribute's and variable's name the same to limit the chance of such ambiguity